# Checkbox data from userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am having an issue returning my checkbox information from an excel userform I created back to the database in excel.  It keeps placing the active worksheet instead of sheet 2 in my excel workbook.

```
Sub CheckBox2_Click()

    Dim iRow As Long

    iRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

    If CheckBox2 Then
        Range("G" & iRow) = "Received"
    Else
        Range("G" & iRow).ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```

I was thinking I need to set the below to make it work but it didn't help.

```
 iRow = Application.Workbooks("PIDParcelUtilities.xlsm").Worksheets("PIDParcelUtilitiesData").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
```

Comment: Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("PIDParcelUtilitiesData")

Answer (score 3):

> *It keeps placing the active worksheet*

That's by design.

> ```
> iRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
> ```

Which worksheet is `Range` referring to?

> ```
> Range("G" & iRow) = "Received"
> ```

Unqualified `Range` calls in a class module (a `UserForm` is a class) implicitly refer to `ActiveSheet`.

Pull the worksheet object reference you mean to work with:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PIDParcelUtilitiesData")
```

And then you can use is to qualify these `Range` calls:

```
iRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

If CheckBox2 Then
    ws.Range("G" & iRow) = "Received"
Else
    ws.Range("G" & iRow).ClearContents
End If
```

Comment: Tweaking to the above gives an error message (Variable not defined) when using ws.Rows.Count

Comment: @KelliGlover then declare the variable? The above has a `Dim` statement for that.